# Saving Array to a Session and Retrieve it, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

So **$token** here is an array of data from the database, I would like to retrieve it in the **view**. I know that the data is already there by using `print_r($this->session->all_userdata());` but I would like to retrieve the values from the **$token** array and use it.

**Controller:**

```
$token['answer']=$this->Qmodel->get_answers();
$data= array(
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'is_logged'=> 1,
    $token
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this one,I hope it will help you

```
 $token['answer']=$this->Qmodel->get_answers();
    $data= array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged'=> 1,
                'token' => $token['answer'] // assign $token['answer'] array into token
                );

    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

get `$token['answer']` array data from session:

```
$token_from_session = $this->session->userdata('token'); //return $token['answer'] array
```